# Java execute chromedriver on linux server

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm playing around with Eclipse, Selenium and chromedriver to facilitate headless retrieval of website data. While I have it working nicely from my laptop, I have deployed a WAR version to a Java/Linux hosted service and am receiving the following error indicating it can't find chromedriver.

Type Exception Report

Message :

```
The driver executable does not exist: /drivers/chromedriver
```

Description :

```
The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /drivers/chromedriver
    com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
    org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    com.carsales.rego.CarRegoAction.doPost(CarRegoAction.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Originally I had the windows location C:\java\selenium\drivers\chromedriver.exe

But I uploaded the Linux version and placed in "/drivers/chromedriver"

Partial Code looks like this...

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String carRegistrationNumer = request.getParameter("cargo");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "/drivers/chromedriver");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.addArguments("headless");
       options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");

    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

And yes I've set permissions for folder and chromedriver to 777 (chmod 777) so should be OK - just can't find it.

Please help...

Answer (score 3):

As you are using *chromedriver* in *headless* mode on *Linux* platform you should use the following *options* :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/drivers/chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

> **Note** : If you are using *chromedriver* in *headless* mode on *Linux* platform the argument **disable-gpu** is crucial and mandatory. See [*Getting Started with Headless Chrome*](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Try using these options in chrome driver:-

```
        Options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        Options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        Options.addArguments("disable-notifications");
        Options.addArguments("allow-running-insecure-content");
```

Comment: Thanks but execution doesn't get that far - I will keep these options in mind if further issues but I tried and expected the same. I think I have the path correct and the file is there so no idea why it can't find it.

Comment: Have you set the path variable?

Answer (score 0):

In Exception, threre is "The driver executable does not exist: /drivers/chromedriver" so You should check if path is correct.

If you would like to have order in files, You can place driver in Your resources directory for Java project eg.
"src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver"